# Sprite Moving game python

Tags: python-2.7, inheritance, pygame

I am doing a [tutorial](http://programarcadegames.com/index.php?chapter=lab_sprite_moving&lang=en) for python (http://programarcadegames.com/) and am stuck on lab 14: Sprite Moving.

The linked page has steps and I am stuck on step 5. Specifically I think I have issues with the **GoodBlock** class I made. I think I am inheriting wrong from my Block class I also made per instructions. I am using Python 2.7 and am pretty sure I used the super function right but am not sure. When I run my code, I am suppose to get a display of green, red and a blue sprites movable via my arrow keys. With the **GoodBlock** class, it is suppose to override the update method (I think?) and also add random movement of the good (green) sprites.

However when I replace all my instances of the Block() class with GoodBlock(), I only get my player sprite to appear, and it seems to be applying the update() function from GoodBlock()

Here is all my code. And here is an example of the prorgam working prior to this step. Here is a [link](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1vhjFnu48hVswh7cKPutvAMCQF3OSSa_g?usp=sharing) to the sprites and the sound files. 
[image]

```
#********************************************
# Latest working version of collect block game with sprite graphics
#Seperated into multiple files. block_library is my class
#
#lab14v1.py
#********************************************

import pygame
import random
#from block_library import *
import block_library
import goodblock_library



# Define some colors
BLACK    = (   0,   0,   0)
WHITE    = ( 255, 255, 255)
RED      = ( 255,   0,   0)





# Initialize Pygame
pygame.init()

# Set the height and width of the screen
screen_width = 700
screen_height = 400
screen = pygame.display.set_mode([screen_width, screen_height])

pygame.display.set_caption("Collect Blocks")


#drawing text on the screen, selecting font to use
font = pygame.font.SysFont('Calibri', 25, True, False)




# This is a list of 'sprites.' Each block in the program is
# added to this list. The list is managed by a class called 'Group.'
block_list = pygame.sprite.Group()

# This is a list of every sprite. All blocks and the player block as well.
all_sprites_list = pygame.sprite.Group()

bad_block_list = pygame.sprite.Group()



for i in range(50):
    # This represents a block
    block = block_library.Block("goodBlk.png")

    #block = goodblock_library.GoodBlock("goodBlk.png")

    # Set a random location for the block
    block.rect.x = random.randrange(screen_width)
    block.rect.y = random.randrange(screen_height)


    badBlock = block_library.Block("badBlk.png")
    #badBlock = goodblock_library.GoodBlock("badBlk.png")
    badBlock.rect.x = random.randrange(screen_width)
    badBlock.rect.y = random.randrange(screen_height)

    # Add the block to the list of objects
    block_list.add(block)
    all_sprites_list.add(block)

    bad_block_list.add(badBlock) #adds badBlock to list of blocks for collision
    all_sprites_list.add(badBlock) #adds badBlocks to list of all blocks



# Create a RED player block
player = block_library.Block("playerBlk.png" )
#player = goodblock_library.GoodBlock("playerBlk.png")
all_sprites_list.add(player)

#Loop until the user clicks the close button.
done = False

# Used to manage how fast the screen updates
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

score = 0


#for sound:

good_sound = pygame.mixer.Sound("good_blockSnd.wav")

bad_sound = pygame.mixer.Sound("bad_blockSnd.wav")

#col_sound = pygame.mixer.Sound("bumpSnd.wav")




# -------- Main Program Loop -----------
while not done:
    for event in pygame.event.get(): # User did something
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT: # If user clicked close
            done = True # Flag that we are done so we exit this loop

            # --- Game logic should go here
            # Set the speed based on the key pressed
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                player.changespeed(-3, 0)
            elif event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                player.changespeed(3, 0)
            elif event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                player.changespeed(0, -3)
            elif event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                player.changespeed(0, 3)

        # Reset speed when key goes up (if not included it goes off in one direction)
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                player.changespeed(3, 0)
            elif event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                player.changespeed(-3, 0)
            elif event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                player.changespeed(0, 3)
            elif event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                player.changespeed(0, -3)    




    # Clear the screen
    screen.fill(WHITE)





    # See if the player block has collided with anything.
    blocks_hit_list = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(player, block_list, True) 





    blocks_hit_list2 = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(player, bad_block_list, True)

    # Check the list of collisions.
    for block in blocks_hit_list:
        score += 1
        #print( score )
        good_sound.play()




    for block in blocks_hit_list2:
        score = score - 1
        bad_sound.play()
        #print(score) #this will print to console,
        # Note: This line creates an image of the letters,
        # but does not put it on the screen yet.




    #to display score on screen:    
    # Note: This line creates an image of the letters,
    # but does not put it on the screen yet. 
    text = font.render("Score:" + str(score), True,BLACK)
    # Put the image of the text on the screen at 250x250
    screen.blit(text, [250, 250])


    # Draw all the spites using the Group class method draw, to loop through each sprite in list (all_sprite_list) and call draw
    all_sprites_list.draw(screen)

    #update sprites speed
    all_sprites_list.update()    





    # Limit to 60 frames per second
    clock.tick(60)

    # Go ahead and update the screen with what we've drawn.
    pygame.display.flip()

pygame.quit()
```

.
.
.

```
    # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Block class for sprites. block_library.py

"""
import pygame
import pygame.mixer
import random


# Define some colors
BLACK    = (   0,   0,   0)
WHITE    = ( 255, 255, 255)
RED      = ( 255,   0,   0)


#initizlize mixer for sound
pygame.mixer.init(44100, -16, 2, 2048)

#define sound for wall coll
col_sound = pygame.mixer.Sound("bumpSnd.wav")


# This class represents the ball        
# It derives from the "Sprite" class in Pygame
class Block(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

    # READ BEFORE USING:
    # This constructor lets you use any graphic:
    # my_sprite = Block("any_graphic.png")
    # But if you DON'T want any graphic, use the following instead:

    def __init__(self, filename):
        # Call the parent class (Sprite) constructor
        #super().__init__() 
        super(Block, self).__init__()

        # Create an image of the block, and fill it with a color.
        # This could also be an image loaded from the disk.
        self.image = pygame.image.load(filename).convert()

        # Set background color to be transparent. Adjust to WHITE if your
        # background is WHITE.
        self.image.set_colorkey(BLACK)

        # Fetch the rectangle object that has the dimensions of the image
        # image.
        # Update the position of this object by setting the values 
        # of rect.x and rect.y
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()

        self.change_x = 0
        self.change_y = 0


        #class method to have speed/position for block
    def changespeed(self, x, y):
        self.change_x = self.change_x + x
        self.change_y = self.change_y + y

    #update rectangle object with position/speed of block
    def update(self):
        self.rect.x = self.change_x + self.rect.x
        self.rect.y = self.change_y + self.rect.y 

        #boundry check, plays sound when colides at screen.
        if self.rect.x > 670:
            self.rect.x = 670
            col_sound.play()
        if self.rect.x < 0:
            self.rect.x = 0
            col_sound.play()
        if self.rect.y < 0:
            self.rect.y = 0
            col_sound.play()
        if self.rect.y > 370:
            self.rect.y = 370
            col_sound.play()
```

.
.
.

```
    #GoodBlock class , goodblock_library.py
import block_library

import random

# Define some colors
BLACK    = (   0,   0,   0)
WHITE    = ( 255, 255, 255)
RED      = ( 255,   0,   0)



class GoodBlock(block_library.Block):
    def __init__(self, filename):
        super(GoodBlock, self).__init__(filename)
        # Call the parent/super class constructor first 
        # READ BEFORE USING:
    # This constructor lets you use any graphic:
    # my_sprite = Block("any_graphic.png")
    # But if you DON'T want any graphic, use the following instead:

    def changespeed(self, x, y):
        super(GoodBlock,self).changespeed(x,y)


    #update rectangle object with position/speed of block
    def update(self):
        #self.rect.x = self.change_x + self.rect.x
        #self.rect.y = self.change_y + self.rect.y 
        super(GoodBlock, self).update()

        self.rect.x = random.randrange(-3, 3)
        self.rect.y = random.randrange(-3, 3)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You set the positions of the `GoodBlock`s to new random values between -3 and 3 (exclusive) each frame in the `update` method.

```
self.rect.x = random.randrange(-3, 3)
self.rect.y = random.randrange(-3, 3)
```

That means they are placed on the player who immediately collects them.

If you want to make the blocks jiggle, you can increment the x and y coords:

```
self.rect.x += random.randrange(-3, 4)
self.rect.y += random.randrange(-3, 4)
```

To make them move a bit nicer, I'd implement a timer (just a frame counter in this example) and change the velocity of the sprites after a time limit is reached:

```
class GoodBlock(Block):
    def __init__(self, image):
        super(GoodBlock, self).__init__(image)
        self.velocity_x = random.randrange(-1, 2)
        self.velocity_y = random.randrange(-1, 2)
        self.counter = 0

    def update(self):
        super(GoodBlock, self).update()
        self.counter += 1
        if self.counter >= 60:  # Every 60 frames.
            self.counter = 0
            # Change the velocity.
            self.velocity_x = random.randrange(-1, 2)
            self.velocity_y = random.randrange(-1, 2)

        self.rect.x += self.velocity_x
        self.rect.y += self.velocity_y
```

Actually, I'd use [vectors](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/math.html#pygame.math.Vector2) to get finer movement. `pygame.Rect`  coordinates can only be incremented by integers.

Comment: I recommend the [steering video tutorials](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g1jo_qsO5c4&index=4&list=PLsk-HSGFjnaHYvbjMbTQG6kLhhZHLzdb3) here.

Comment: oh wow something so simple I missed. Thanks a million. Also as an aside, how would I only get the green sprite to move? I think that is what my tutorial asks of me. With your edit above all of the sprites jiggle. (which is really cool too) (Should I edit this question into the main question?)

Comment: The red blocks should still be `block_library.Block` instances.

Comment: BTW, I also suggest to load the images once when the program starts not inside of the `__init__` methods, otherwise the images have to be loaded from the hard disk again and again when an instance is created.